# Select record and get closeTime and OpenTime from the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

[image]

What i want is the following result:

```
InteractionID - OpenTime - CloseTime
```

Opentime is the `DATE_STAMP` where `UPDATE_TYPE = "Open"` and 
CloseTime is is the `DATE_STAMP` where `UPDATE_TYPE = "Close"`

I have the following SQL Query:

```
Select DISTINCT A.INTERACTION_ID as idd, 
(Select B.DATE_STAMP from dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY B WHERE B.UPDATE_TYPE = 'Open'  and B.INTERACTION_ID = A.INTERACTION_ID) as OpenTime, 
(Select TOP 1 C.DATE_STAMP from dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY C WHERE C.UPDATE_TYPE = 'Close' and C.INTERACTION_ID = A.INTERACTION_ID) as CloseTime 
  from dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY A where DATEPART(year, A.DATE_STAMP) > 2014
```

It work kinda ok, but i have **2 questions:**

1. Is this a correct way to do this? It seems like a slow query, so perhaps there is a way to optimize this?
2. Instead of checking that the datestamp is > than 2014, I would like to find the results where OpenTime is less than 30 days, how do i do this?

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: What should happen with results that don't have an Open or Close time?  (that is, with results that are incomplete?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this query

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.INTERACTION_ID as idd,
    A.DATE_STAMP AS OpenTime,
    B.DATE_STAMP AS CloseTime,
FROM dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY A
    JOIN dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY B ON A.INTERACTION_ID = B.INTERACTION_ID
    AND A.UPDATE_TYPE = 'Open'
    AND B.UPDATE_TYPE = 'Close'
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,A.DATE_STAMP,GETDATE())<30
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```
SELECT
    INTERACTION_ID,
    update_open,
    update_close,
    datediff('d',update_open,update_close) AS diff
FROM
    (SELECT 
        INTERACTION_ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN update_type = 'Open' THEN DATE_STAMP ELSE NULL END) AS update_open,
        MAX(CASE WHEN update_type = 'Close' THEN DATE_STAMP ELSE NULL END) AS update_close
    FROM    
        SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY
    WHERE
        DATEPART(YEAR, DATE_STAMP) > 2014 AND
        UPDATE_TYPE IN('Open','Close')
    GROUP BY
        INTERACTION_ID) mx
WHERE
    datediff('d',update_open,update_close)  < 30
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table with itself.

First for Open record, and join with the closed records.

```
SELECT 
    O.INTERACTION_ID,
    O.DATE_STAMP DATE_STAMP_OPEN,
    C.DATE_STAMP DATE_STAMP_CLOSE
FROM dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY O
INNER JOIN dbo.SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY C ON
    O.INTERACTION_ID = C.INTERACTION_ID AND
    O.UPDATE_TYPE = "Open" AND
    C.UPDATE_TYPE = "Closed" 
WHERE 
    O.DATE_STAMP > DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE())
```

You can replace GETDATE with a variable if you want to define the date.

With inner join you well only get "Full records" both a Open and Close.

With Left you will get records that are still Open.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you have some options now, I'll just throw one more in:

```
;With CTE AS 
(
    SELECT INTERACTION_ID,
            CASE WHEN UPDATE_TYPE = 'open' THEN
            DATE_STAMP
            END As OpenTime,
            CASE WHEN UPDATE_TYPE = 'close' THEN
            DATE_STAMP
            END As CloseTime

    FROM SD_INTERACTIONS_HISTORY
    WHERE UPDATE_TYPE IN('open', 'close')
)

SELECT INTERACTION_ID, MAX(OpenTime) As OpenTime, MAX(CloseTime) As CloseTime
FROM CTE
GROUP BY INTERACTION_ID
```

(Personally, I like the self join option better, but I was already writing this so...)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with some join criteria and a `DATE` comparison on the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
CREATE TABLE #interactions
    (
      id INT ,
      date_stamp DATETIME ,
      update_type NVARCHAR(10)
    )

INSERT  INTO #interactions
        ( id, date_stamp, update_type )
VALUES  ( 1, DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE()), 'Open' ),
        ( 1, DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()), 'Update' ),
        ( 1, GETDATE(), 'Close' )

SELECT DISTINCT
        i.id ,
        iOpen.date_stamp OpenTime ,
        iClose.date_stamp CloseTime
FROM    #interactions i
        INNER JOIN #interactions iOpen ON iOpen.id = i.id
                                          AND iOpen.update_type = 'Open'
        INNER JOIN #interactions iClose ON iClose.id = i.id
                                           AND iClose.update_type = 'Close'
WHERE   iOpen.date_stamp >= DATEADD(DAY, -30, GETDATE())

DROP TABLE #interactions
```